# Total refresh in Checkout page on city change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an Ecommerce site running Woocommerce.

My client noticed that the Total in checkout page keeps refresh ( recalculate ) when changing any of the billing address fields i.e Billing City.

I don't want to dequeue the checkout.js file since it is needed for some calculations.

I tried to deactivate all plugins and change the theme but these didn't fix the problem.
How can I stop Total recalculate in checkout page when changing the City?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a normal behavior.
There is a hook or function that is ran once all mandatory address fields are entered that allows the site owner to set different shipping rates / options depending on address.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for your reply, but I think it can be improved. The question should be added as a comment, not as an answer. I think it is a good idea that this can be related to the shipping rate calculations. But you could add how to check that or how to get rid of the reload. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks Rank! I am a bit of a noob here,
Although I have just tried to comment and it says I need a reputation of 50+:(